# html/css breadcrumbs as in the image

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck to start the CSS to build breadcrumbs as in the image link below.Thanks any for help :)

image - http://s1015.photobucket.com/user/dbf1655/media/bred.png.html

this is my html

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Course</li>
  <li>Subject</li>
  <li class="active">English</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: All items except the last one should be links, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways. Here is one that doesn't require any extra markup:

```css
.breadcrumbs {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.breadcrumbs:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}

.breadcrumbs li {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.breadcrumbs li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Course</li>
  <li>Subject</li>
  <li class="active">English</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the background image witch looks like part of that (with line and dot) for each of `<li>` element. That can be help.

Comment: hmm,but I have to make this be dynamic for future.